# The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection using SqlQuery Class in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-query-store

I am invoking a stored procedure as follows:

```cs
var filterParameter = new SqlParameter("Column", filter);
var criteriaParameter = new SqlParameter("Criteria", criteria);
var countParameter = new SqlParameter("ItemPerPage", count);
var tenantParameter = new SqlParameter("TenantId", tenantId);
var pageParameter = new SqlParameter("Page", page);
string sortTypeQuery = "DESC";
if (sortType == OrderByType.Ascending) sortTypeQuery = "ASC";
var sortTypeParameter = new SqlParameter("SortType", sortTypeQuery);
var tableParameter = new SqlParameter("Table", "TenantSubscribers");

return await Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(
    "EXEC [dbo].[Filters] @Column, @Criteria, @ItemPerPage, @TenantId, @SortType, @Table, @Page",
    filterParamter, criteriaParameter, countParameter, tenantParameter, sortTypeParameter, pageParameter,
    tableParameter, pageParameter).ToListAsync();
```

As a result it generates an exception:

> The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection

Comment: Please your code as text, not as an image!

Comment: I've manually copied the data from the image. Please: always paste code as *code*, not as an image; it would have taken you seconds - it took me a lot longer

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and patience. I am something new in this.

Answer (score 1):

You have `pageParameter` two times. Should be only once.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and patience. I am something new in this.

Answer (score 1):

You are providing `pageParameter` twice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and patience. I am something new in this.